# Bayesian parameter estimation

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, stochastic-differential-equations, bayesian-probability

I am generally not that knowledgeable for math, so if my question is too broad or inaccurate, please let me know.

I am currently reading a paragraph of one paper (https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/doc/papers/karl_bayes_dyn.pdf), which is about Bayesian parameter estimation of nonlinear dynamical system. Here is the link for screenshoted paragraph ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeuYo.png)).

I have been going through more or less well entire paragraphs but there is one particular transition that I could not figure out, which is about Equation (13). How I can get specified equations for 'parameter covariance' and 'conditional mean parameters given a data' as stated in the paper?

Comment: You need to iteratively solve for them by numerical optimization. teh paper propose you use Expectation Maximization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm , which is described within the paper on the following pages.